# How can I pass a string as a parameter to Python's csv's writerow?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, csv, parameters

The following code works (in Python 2.7) for creating a .csv file:

```
with open('court_addresses.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['court_name', 'full_court_link', 'clean_address']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerow({'court_name': court_name, 'full_court_link': full_court_link, 'clean_address': clean_address})
```

However, instead of the above syntax for writerow, what if I have a variable defined as follows:

```
row = "'court_name': court_name, 'full_court_link': full_court_link, 'clean_address': clean_address"
```

Unfortunately, this does not work.  How can I make the following call:

```
writer.writerow({row})
```

and have it work (in Python 2.7)?  Currently, it throws the following error:

ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames

Clearly, the csv writerow() function doesn't like a string as a parameter, even though I know that will work for other functions.

Comment: Why are you doing it like that? Where is this string coming from, why isn't it a real dictionary?

Comment: The fields are read in a binary file source, one field at a time

Comment: So read the file and create a dictionary from the data.

Comment: How does a binary file source create a string with variable names in it? This really seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Thanks!  I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `writerow()` has to be a dictionary or list. A string containing the representation of dictionary contents is not automatically parsed as the dictionary.

If your string just contained data you could use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse it. But since your string contains variable names, you have to use `eval()` to evaluate it.

```
writer.writerow(eval('{' + row + '}'))
```

This is very dangerous, since `eval()` can execute arbitrary code. I suggest you find another way to do what you're doing. E.g. make it an actual dictionary:

```
row = {'court_name': court_name, 'full_court_link': full_court_link, 'clean_address': clean_address}
writer.writerow({row})
```

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed the problem.  I was looking for something that would treat it as a literal rather than a string.

Comment: FYI, `ast.literal_eval()` will treat it as a literal (you still need to concatenate `{` and `}`. But since you have variables in it, that won't work.